# How should I implement Parse user authentication as middleware in Node Express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

I'm creating an Express app and using Parse for the user login and registration. I'm trying to create a middleware to check whether users are logged in for certain pages such as the user account page.

This is the code I have which throws an error as the middleware function doesn't have access to the Parse object. Can I pass it through to the middleware somehow or is there a far better way of defining the middleware function somewhere else where I can make it aware of the Parse object?

```
module.exports = function(app, Parse){

  app.get('user', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next){
    // do something
  }

}

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){

  if(Parse.User.authenticated()){
    return next();
  } else {
    // do something else
  }

}
```

Comment: You can define middleware for all request via `app.use` in main js file.

Answer (score 0):

Either create the function inside your export function scope, or return a function so you can pass in `Parse` as an argument.

```
module.exports = function (app, Parse) {
    app.get('user', isLoggedIn(Parse), function (req, res, next) {
            // do something
    });
};

function isLoggedIn(Parse) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (Parse.User.authenticated()) {
            return next();
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ben thanks I ended up just making the bloody thing a Global variable in the end but your returning a function idea looks like what I was trying to achieve.